# How to get default values from Typescript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

lets say I have

```
 type DataItems = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  subItems?: Array<DataItemChild>;
  checked: boolean;
  isEdit:boolean;
};
```

I defined an object as

```
const myObj = {} as DataItems;
```

when I inspect `myObj` I see `{}`.

I was expectiong:

```
   {
      id: 0,
      title: '',
      subItems:[],
      checked: false,
      isEdit:false
    }
```

I could define my objest as :

```
  const myObj = {
    id : 0,
    title: '',
    subItems: [],
    checked: false,
    isEdit: false,
  } as DataItems;
```

But I wonder is there a way to get this as default without manually needing to define it?

Comment: dont use `as` when possible. try `const myObj: DateItems = {}`. So will Typescript will throw an error that you are missing some props. To your question: not that im aware of.

Comment: Typescript is not for runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do that is to make a `class`, but you always need to use `new DataItems` to "get" the default values.

```
type DataItemChild = any;

class DataItems {
  id: number = 0;
  title: string = '';
  subItems: DataItemChild[] = []
  checked: boolean = false;
  isEdit:boolean = false;
};

const myObj = new DataItems();
console.dir(myObj);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBJYEC2BhAFgSwDYAmUAvFHAHYgDcAsAFD0DGecAzq7AsqmhwN70oUHAQBcUcgFc0AIwgAnElAAMtOkOA5geCONbB5OcgHMlAcjNqhrSTJTpW4+InuZchANoBdJd8FRGLAhGAGsIMSgZAHsonQolADM4PFYIK2FWAFECLVFo2Ih40iSUtPoAXzUmKPJ9KDQQAHkZACslcggAd04XHlYACgBKNUYa1gKAOhz5fobmluH6IA)

Comment: This is a way I guess. The thing that I am after if there is a typescript built-in feature that simply does this for me. Your solution is good but it still involves me writing this manually.  same as   const myObj = {
    id : 0,
    title: '',
    subItems: [],
    checked: false,
    isEdit: false,
  } as DataItems; 

and using it as a default type.

Comment: I will accept this since it is a solution, I think what I am after is something typescript does not support at this moment in time.

Comment: What you want does not exist in TypeScript or JavaScript. The benefit over setting them is you need to set them every time, manually. Also of note: using `as` just tells the compiler you know better - it does nothing at runtime nor any validation to confirm it "works".

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way in typescript which gives you default value without initializing it.
How would typescript know that you want to initialize number from 0, string should be empty, boolean should be empty and so on.
You can do the following:

```
type DataItems = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  subItems?: Array<DataItemChild>;
  checked: boolean;
  isEdit:boolean;
};

const myObj : DataItems = {
      id: 0,
      title: '',
      subItems:[],
      checked: false,
      isEdit:false
    };
```